# ¿por que me produce una excepción?

Tags: c#, wpf

Se produce cuando lanzo por segunda vez el hilo hs

```
    Thread hs;
    hs = new Thread(()=>Playsound(sound));


while (bstate==-1)
{
    t = Int16.Parse(bpm.Text);
    t = 60000 / t;

    hs.Start();

    cajas[compas-1].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    cajas[0].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    await Task.Delay(t);

    for (int k = 1; k < compas-1; k++)
    {


        hs.Start();
        cajas[k-1].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        cajas[k].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        await Task.Delay(t);
    }

    hs.Start();

    cajas[compas - 2].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    cajas[compas - 1].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    await Task.Delay(t);

}
```

Comment: Esto ya lo preguntaste antes. Varias personas te pidieron que colocaras la excepción que te lanza y no respondiste.

Comment: Hola, puedes poner el error que te da, para poder darte una respuesta. Un Saludo.

Comment: @YvánEcarri posible no, ha hecho la misma pregunta 2 veces y no se ha preocupado de mejorarla en nada, reporte al canto

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Así es, pero cuando haces un reporte de pregunta duplicada automáticamente se crea el comentario con este texto. Hasta que pase algún usuario y revise mi reporte de pregunta duplicada se considera "posible" :)

Comment: Edgar, no dupliques pregunta. Pulsa en `editar` bajo tu pregunta original para mejorar su explicacion e informacion segun [ask]. Un saludo